# First ever Contribution deleted?

Tags: support, user-accounts

First time post and provided what I thought was a very much valid and relevant answer to a question. I then took the time to register and validated my email address in the hope that I could become a valued member of the community.
With 20 years experience in computing and building PC's I thought I would have something to contribute?

Unfortunately my [first post](https://superuser.com/a/989068/4377) was deleted by Sathya without explanation. Yes I have read the 'why was my post deleted help section' and cannot see how or why what I'd written didn't comply with guidelines.

Rant over and sorry for any offense caused. I will not return, you may also delete this one without explanation too if you wish.

Comment: Looks like its essentially a duplicate of ... 2? maybe 3 other answers. That might be it.

Comment: @op, Without weighing in on your abstract question, I would probably have left your answer as a Comment instead. Comments are generally lower risk, and people are less picky about them. If the answer is short, and I have not put much (or any) work into crafting a solution for the user (citing documentation, providing indepth explaination, cropping images, etc), I will usually just use a comment. it gets the job done. Thats just my personal take though, and probably not entirely what the mods would want, but thread-drama stresses me out, and I don't come here so authorities can stress me out.

Comment: To continue what @FrankThomas is trying to say, an answer that's been stated already 2-3 times should be **high quality** if it should stand on it's own.

Answer (score 13):

The answer you’d posted is the same that has been duplicated in 4 (5, actually if you consider another deleted answer which repeats the same content) other answers and doesn’t have any significant new information to stand on its own.

While having your post removed isn’t really a good first-time experience and I’m sorry about that, but Super User strives on not being forum-like with repeated posts duplicating the same content.

I’d still encourage you to continue posting, ultimately it’s your choice.

Answer (score -4):

Maybe you were expecting a more friendly and ready to help community here because you thought it would be similar to StackOverflow. Think again... Most 'answers' or 'constructive feedback' are aimed at arguing against what you are trying to do or the way in which you have written your question rather than helping you get to an answer.

Comment: I'm clearing out the comments here. Guys, chill, its only a website. I do take some degree of exception to  "Most 'answers' or 'constructive feedback' are aimed at arguing against what you are trying to do" but if its a really major issue, lets take this to another meta question please! Give examples and we can perhaps see how we can best deal with it if its a real issue. I do believe we're a pretty friendly community and we do try to help within reasonable limits.

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - The schnauzer in me sometimes goes overboard in trying to defend the community. My bad.

Comment: No offence people, but this can be quite true at times... Don't get me wrong, this community can be REALLY HELPFUL, you just have to realize that many, if not most people are literally DYING for reputation, so naturally this become a competitive place... :|